# Optional capture group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I need to parse some HTTP requests and now want to parse the GET parameters.

My current regex is

```
(GET|POST)\s(.*)(\?.*)\sHTTP\/(\d\.\d)
```

I want to match the following:

```
"GET /page.html HTTP/1.1"
  => group1: "GET" group2: "/page.html" group3: "" group4: "1.1"

"GET /page.html?param1=foo&param2=bar HTTP/1.1"
  => group1: "GET" group2: "/page.html" group3: "param1=foo&param2=bar" group4: "1.1"
```

My current regex only matches the second one

Comment: what would you like to capture in above input?

Comment: @AkashKC the GET parameters. but only if they exist. If they don't exist it should just be an empty group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the third capturing group with an optional non-capturing group and use a lazy `*?` quantifier within the second capturing group to match as few characters into Group 2 as possible (for Group 3 that matches query params to grab those data if present):

```
(GET|POST)\s(.*?)(?:(\?.*)\s)?HTTP\/(\d\.\d)
               ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Details**:

- `(GET|POST)` - Group 1: either `GET` or `POST` substrings
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible (so as to yield all the params in the query string to the next capturing group if the query string is present)
- `(?:(\?.*)\s)?` - an optional (1 or 0 times) non-capturing group matching:

  - `(\?.*)` - Group 3 capturing a `?`, any 0+ chars as many as possible, up to the last...
  - `\s`  - witespace
- `HTTP\/` - a `HTTP/` literal char sequence
- `(\d\.\d)` - Group 4 capturing a digit, `.` and a digit.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hXP5m0/2).

[image]

Now, if there is no `?` inside the string, Group 3 will not capture anything, as the obligatory `?` and `\s` are optional *as part of a sequence*.

Comment: but I want the GET parameters in a seperate group

Comment: yours can also be achieved with `(GET|POST)\s(.*)\sHTTP\/(\d\.\d)`

Comment: Ok, use lazy dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : what does `(?:(\?.*)\s)?` mean?

Comment: Just `'(GET|POST)\\s(.*)(\\??.*)\\sHTTP\\/(\\d\\.\\d)'` should work (with an extra `?`).

Comment: `(?:(\?.*)\s)?` is an optional non-capturing group matching `?`, any 0+ chars as many as possible (that text is saved into a memory buffer as the pattern is inside a capturing group) and then a whitespace